# ansible "unarchive" module is not working as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

my aim is that extract the .zip file in the controller to the specific folder in application servers (because i have another script with this path specified for calling the package).

i was trying for 2 conditions

1)  check the target servers directory present or not (eg: /opt/mypack). if it present skip else create directory.

2) check the above directory already have the extracted file or not. if no extract, if yes skip extract.

I tried with below playbook where i want to extract 2 .zip packages to all target servers specific location (/opt/mypack and /opt/mypack2)

```
 ---

   - name: Extract CLM-Web Package into /opt/mypack
     hosts: localhost,IHS,CCM,RM
     vars:
       source_dir: /etc/ansible/roles/IBM2/files/mypack.zip
       dest_dir: /opt/mypack
     tasks:
       - name: check the folder existance
         stat: path=/opt/mypack
         register: folder_exist

       - name: create directory
         command: mkdir /opt/mypack
         when: folder_exist.stat.exists == False

       - name: extract the .zip file
         unarchive:
           src: "{{ source_dir }}"
           dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/"
         when: folder_exist.stat.exists == True

    - name: Extract CLM Installation Package to /opt/mypack
      hosts: localhost,CCM,RM
      vars:
        source_dir: /etc/ansible/roles/IBM2/files/mypack2.zip
         dest_dir: /opt/mypack2
      tasks:
        - name: check the folder existance
          stat: path=/opt/mypack2
          register: folder_exist

       - name: create directory
         command: mkdir /opt/mypack2
         When: folder_exist.stat.exists == False

       - name: extract the .zip file
         unarchive:
            src: "{{ source_dir }}"
            dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/"
         when: folder_exist.stat.exists == True
```

Comment: Instead of checking for the directory, and then creating it via `command: mkdir`, you can use the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/file_module.html#file-module) with `state: directory`. This will ensure that the directory is present - one step instead of two, and you save the `register/when` part as well.

Comment: so will this file module create the directory with the name which we needed prior to unzip ?

Comment: Yes. Please see _Lewis M_'s answer below for a full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you need with the files module and a loop.  I prefer roles.  So, I created the following directory structure:

```
.
+ testunarchive.yml
+ unarchive
  + files
  | + foo1.zip
  | + foo2.tgz
  + tasks
    + main.yml
    + unarchive.yml
```

The foo1.zip and foo2.tgz are just test archive files in zip and compressed tar format.

The testunarchive.yml contains the playbook.  I just tested this on localhost.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - unarchive
...
```

The main.yml task brings in the unarchive.yml file and loops over all tasks in that file.

```
---
- include: unarchive.yml
  loop:
    - { src: foo1.zip, dest: /tmp/foo1 }
    - { src: foo2.tgz, dest: /var/tmp/foo2 }
...
```

The unarchive.yml task file does the actual work of creating the destination directory if it does not exist, and unarchiving the source archive into the destination directory.

```
---
- name: "Creating {{ item.dest }}"
  file:
    path: "{{ item.dest }}"
    state: directory
- name: "Unarchiving {{ item.src }}"
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
...
```

Hopefully something like this will help you.